# Javascript sessionStorage variable not saving correctly

Tags: javascript, forms, sessionstorage

I am trying to save various values from a HTML form to sessionStorage but with the following code I receive the "storeInfo Start" alert but not "StoreInfo End" so I assume there is some error/bug with the sessionStorage code.

I have stripped away other code yet this example is still not working for me, I am using Firefox 45.0.2 if that is relevant however I have used sessionStorage previously with this browser and similar code that I cannot find the difference/s between.

```
function validate () {
    alert("Validate");
    storeInfo();
}

function storeInfo() {
    alert("storeInfo Start");

    sessionStorage.firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;

    alert("StoreInfo End - First Name is: " + sessionStorage.firstName);

}

function init () {
    alert("Init Works!");

    // For apply page
    if (document.getElementById("applyForm") != null) {
        var applyForm = document.getElementById("applyForm");
        applyForm.onsubmit = validate;
    }
 }

window.onload = init;
```

The from the HTML file:

```
<form id="applyForm">
    <p>
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label> 
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" maxlength="25" size="25" required="required" value="ThisIsMyName" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: sessionStorage works that way, the error should be somewhere else

Comment: `document.getElementById("firstName")` has to be returning null or you would see the 2nd alert

Comment: Have you checked your console? may be same origin policy the matter if your form action is targeting different domain.

You should see something like this in your console.

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property
> from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the
> 'allow-same-origin' flag.

Comment: Thankyou very much, I didn't realise that there was an error "The operation is insecure" that was actually blocking saving the data as I have been working locally but was using an echo script on the server. When I uploaded this code to the same domain it's all working again.
Thanks for all your responses

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find such kind of API?

Use:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('firstName', document.getElementById("firstName").value;);
```

...and later `sessionStorage.getItem('firstName');`

Comment: I was shown to use that format in my lecture slides from uni, though this seems to be a better way, except when I use this instead I still have the same issue.

Comment: imho sessionStorage is an object, not an API.  why use methodical access (with quotes, 11 extra chars, and paren-balancing) that we don't use on any other objects? using descriptive names prevents conflicts on the few "reserved" keys, and coders who always use the methods often don't realize that `JSON.stringify(sessionStorage)` and `Object.keys(sessionStorage)` work well and compliment `Object.assign()` to merge batches. but i digress..

Answer (score 0):

I had to add some html to the snippet but when I put it on fiddle it works.

```
<form id="applyForm">
    <p>
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label> 
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" maxlength="25" size="25" required="required" value="ThisIsMyName" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rixlabs/hn0uv4ar/) works

Comment: Apologies, I forgot those other HTML tags were important to copy too.

I'm not sure what the difference is but I still cannot get it to work like this

Comment: even with a raw copy from the fiddle on your pc ?

Comment: Yes, even using just this form in its own HTML file with `<html>` etc. tags and nothing else, I can't get the second "StoreInfo End..."

Comment: I tested my fiddle on firefox chrmoe and even IE and it always works. I don't know how to help you. Sry

Answer (score -1):

May be you can try localStorage, like this:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('firstName')){
        firstName=localStorage.getItem('firstName');
    } 
localStorage.setItem('firstName',document.getElementById("firstName").value;);
```

Comment: Thankyou, I have tried using localStorage instead and I still have the same problem, though I would rather use sessionStorage for this particular application so it is not saved betweeen sessions.